# OpenGL, why this code doesn't work as I expected?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Hello and sorry for asking such a specific question.

I have the following GLSL vertex shader:

```
#version 140

uniform vec2 viewport_size;

in vec2 vertex_position;

in vec2 in_texture_uv;
varying vec2 texture_uv;


void main(void)
{
    texture_uv = in_texture_uv;

    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position / viewport_size, 0, 1);
}
```

and the corresponding fragment shader:

```
#version 140

uniform sampler2D texture_image;

out vec4 out_frag_color;

varying vec2 texture_uv;


void main(void)
{
    out_frag_color = texture(texture_image, texture_uv);
}
```

that produces this output (note the tiny blue dot on the lower left corner):
[image: output_actual]

The strange thing is that if I replace

```
texture_uv = in_texture_uv;
```

with

```
texture_uv = vertex_position;
```

the output becomes: [image: output_vertpos] (note the borders on the bottom and the left).

And finally, If I write:

```
texture_uv = vertex_position;
texture_uv = in_texture_uv;
```

the output is correct: [image: output_correct], and this doesn't make any sense for me...

Could someone explain why this thing happens? Thanks for your time!

---

Relevant code snippets:

```
float[] positionVboData = new float[] {
    // X       Y     U       V
     0.0f,   0.0f,   0f,     0f,
    50.0f,   0.0f,   1f,     0f,
    50.0f,  25.0f,   1f,    .5f,
     0.0f,  50.0f,   0f,     1f,
};
```

.

```
// vertices
GL.GenBuffers(1, out verticesHandle);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, verticesHandle);
GL.BufferData<float>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

// vertices: vertex_position
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL.BindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vertex_position");
GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(float)*4, 0);

// vertices: texture_uv
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
GL.BindAttribLocation(program, 1, "in_texture_uv");
GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(float)*4, sizeof(float) * 2);
```

Texture:

[image: sample_texture]

Comment: I don't think this should be the problem, but you should avoid mixing `varying`/`attribute` (_deprecated_) and `in`/`out`

Comment: Ok, I just tried replacing "varying" with "out" in the vertex shader, and with "in" in the fragment shader.
No change at all.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `vertex_position / viewport_size`? That is not the correct way to transform to window-space.

Comment: Hem... well... this is actually my first modern OpenGL program.
"viewport_size" contains the size of the window I'm rendering in, and the viewport is GL.Viewport(-Width, -Height, Width*2, Height*2);

What is the correct way?

Comment: @bruce965: By multiplying with a proper projection matrix. Also the result of the vertex shader state is in clip space, which spans the coordinate range [-1;1].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is most likely that your `BindAttribLocation()` calls are coming too late:

```
GL.BindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vertex_position");
...
GL.BindAttribLocation(program, 1, "in_texture_uv");
```

We don't see where and how you build your shader program, but based on the context I suspect that you already built your shader program at this point. You need to make the `BindAttribLocation()` calls **before linking the shader program**. Otherwise those locations will not take effect.

If you are ok with increasing the shader version to `330`, you can also specify the location of your vertex shader inputs in the shader code itself, using `layout (location=...)` directives.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved a problem that made my head hurt for a whole day!

Comment: note that some platforms (OSX, namely) also have the `GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location` extension so that you can use `layout (location = ...)` even with shader version `150`

Answer (score 4):

Need more space than the one I have in a comment...

---

Assuming that `GL.Viewport` is actually a wrapper for `glViewport`, then

```
GL.Viewport(-Width, -Height, Width*2, Height*2)
```

makes little sense as it brings 3/4 of the viewport outside your window surface. **Just pass `(0, 0, width, height)` for painting on your entire window**, 0, 0 being in the lower-left corner. If you want to restrict GL output to a subset of your window, adjust the parameter accordingly.

<sub>Technically, glViewport defines the **Normalized Device Coordinates** to **Window Coordinates** transformation for X and Y. It's important to learn about spaces in OpenGL. Spend some time on it.</sub>

That having been said, the vertex shader output is also strange. If you want to "fill your window" with your polygon¹, you don't need to do that strange

```
vertex_position / viewport_size
```

division in your vertex shader.

Remember that the Vertex Shader outputs in *clip coordinates*, after which OpenGL brings your coordinates in *normalized device coordinates* by dividing X, Y, Z by W. Normalized device coordinates range from -1 to 1 in all three dimensions. Only points falling inside this 2x2x2 cube will be actually rasterized.

<sub>Remember what I said about `glViewport`?</sub>

So, what's the trick? Just output coordinates with W=1 so that they're already effectively already in NDC. So if you want a quadrilateral to span across the entire area of your window drawn by GL, just build something like

```
float coords[] = { -1, -1,
                    1, -1,
                    1,  1,
                   -1,  1 };
```

Or, according to your original code, if you want a trapezoid, use something like

```
float coords[] = { -1, -1,
                    1, -1,
                    1,  0,
                   -1,  1 };
```

And then pass them through the vertex shader:

```
in vec2 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

---

¹ Please, make that be a `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, not a `GL_QUAD` nor a `GL_POLYGON`

Comment: `Assuming that GL.Viewport is actually a wrapper for glViewport` yes, I'm using managed code, but the wrapping is direct.


I'm working with that numbers because I'm from software graphic interfaces that prefer integers instead of floats, and I actually wanted that image to be only 50px wide.


I will delegate those computations to the GPU and avoid the futile `uniform vec2 viewport_size;` then.


Thanks for the great explanation!